# How to delete posts on the site?

Tags: support, deletion, deleted-questions, deleted-answers

I would like to delete one of my questions as I managed to solve it. 
However, I do not know how to delete my post.

Can I delete my question? How can I delete a post? Under which circumstances is it possible to delete posts? Does deletion work for answers?

Comment: The radius is 4 inches, and the arc length of a semicircle is $\pi r= \pi 4$. The configuration is a one dimensional wire bent into the purple segments (connected) and there's no area involved.

Comment: Why would you want to delete your post? Are you afraid of getting caught or something?

Comment: No. It's because I already realized my mistake and I don't want to waste some people's time by viewing a post that has already been solved.

Comment: The poster cannot find the Delete button.

Comment: You can find details here: [How does deleting work? What can cause a post to be deleted, and what does that actually mean? What are the criteria for deletion?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5221/how-does-deleting-work-what-can-cause-a-post-to-be-deleted-and-what-does-that)

Comment: Two downvotes already - better to close/delete this question and re-answer a better version, IMO. I am not sure if there is a suitable duplicate.

Comment: @Carl Closing this will push the question back to the main site as rejected migration (there are f-r that this should not happen but I think it still is the case). Thus doing so  does not strike me as a good idea at all. The question is also pretty easy to *improve*, besides it not being all that bad.

Answer (score 5):

Just below your question you should see several links: share edit close delete flag. Click on the one which says *delete*. (If you hover over this link, the tooltip says: "vote to delete this post". I agree that this might sound a bit confusing.) The same is true for answers.

When you click on delete, a pop up window will appear. It will either ask you to confirm whether you really want to delete your post or explain the reasons why you cannot delete the question.

In some situations you are not allowed to delete your own question. For example, you cannot delete a question which has an upvoted answer (or an accepted answer or more than one answer). 
For answer-deletion there are less restrictions. Yet an accepted answer cannot be deleted.

And unregistered users are not allowed to deleted their posts at all.

More details about deletion can be found here: [How does deleting work? What can cause a post to be deleted, and what does that actually mean? What are the criteria for deletion?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5221/how-does-deleting-work-what-can-cause-a-post-to-be-deleted-and-what-does-that)